# How handle InterruptedException and ExecutionException in stream API

Tags: java

I have list of items and iterating using stream API and value getting from Future object. Its throwing compile time exception .How to handle in this case

I have tried wrapper method but still issue not resolved.

```
Future<Map<Integer, String>> serviceInfoFuture = executor.submit(new Callable<Map<Integer, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Map<Integer, String> call() throws Exception {
                        return serviceUtil.getServiceInfoForTenant(Integer.parseInt(tenantId));
                    }
                });
List<String> listOfServiceNameAndIds = response.getItems().stream().map(e -> uncheckCall(serviceInfoFuture.get().get(Integer.parseInt(e)+"="+e))).collect(Collectors.toList());

public static <T> T uncheckCall(Callable<T> callable) {
    try { return callable.call(); }
    catch (RuntimeException e) { throw e; }
    catch (InterruptedException  |ExecutionException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
    catch (Exception e){throw new RuntimeException(e);}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't handling `InterruptedException` and `ExecutionException` thrown by `serviceInfoFuture.get()`.

```
.map(e -> {
  try {
    return uncheckCall(serviceInfoFuture.get().get(Integer.parseInt(e) + "=" + e));
  } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException exception) {
    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
  }
})
```

`uncheckCall` only deals with exceptions thrown from `callable.call()`.